# Is it possible to add an 'unfollow' button that will work for Twitter, Instagram, Facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, instagram

I'd like to create a page that presents the user with a specific account, let's say Donald Rumsfeld, and allow them to unfollow this person from the site by clicking "unfollow". Is this possible?

Comment: You would have to look at the individual API's

Answer (score 1):

You mean a single `UNFOLLOW` button that will allow your visitor to unfollow  a particular user's Facebook, Twitter & Instagram profile?

If that's the case, then you need to dig into the APIs & SDKs of these three social networks. My guess is that the latest version of Facebook Graph API doesn't allow such things to be done programmatically. In fact, FB removed many things that were earlier very handy for the developers, in the new Graph API as part of reducing spammy and unwanted apps.

A simple alternative solution is to use the [Follow Button plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button) of Facebook. You could just echo the profile link of the FB user at runtime on it like this:

```
<div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

So, if your visitor is already logged in to Facebook and have been following that user, then your visitor could simply click the faded blue `Follow` button of this plugin, allowing them to unfollow that profile!

For the other two social networks, just go through their APIs.

Comment: Hmm curious, I can't seem to get the follow button to show up whatsoever. I've gone through the official Facebook code gen as well. Nothing shows up at all... is it that I can't run the code locally?

Comment: Yeah it won't work if you are just double clicking and opening the html file on your browser. Either it should be opened from localhost(via WAMP/XAMPP or any other local servers) using the `http://` url or you should upload the page to an online server and access it.